# EXC_BAD_ACCESS with IKImageBrowserView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, exc-bad-access, ikimagebrowserview

I am developping an application using an IKImageBrowserView.
Randomly it crashed and the issue is in the IKImageBrowserView:
Here is the stack trace where it fails:

I've seen n the web that this issue is known and fixable, but never seen the solution...
[image: Stack trace]
If you have any idea or pointer, your help will be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: If you are running garbage collected then IKImageBrowserView may have random jitters. I have experienced this in the past

Comment: Could you edit your question and post the entire backtrace?

Answer (score 0):

You should profile your project with NSZombies enabled or using instruments, this can do an idea about your issue